# PHP: Calling another class' method

Tags: php, oop

I'm still learning OOP so this might not even be possible (although I would be surprised if so), I need some help calling another classes method.

For example in `ClassA I` have this method:

```
function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

now from `ClassB` (different file, but in the same directory), I want to call `ClassA`'s `getName()`, how do I do that? I tried to just do an `include()` but that does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: share the code you are using to call getName()

Comment: Does class B have any relation to class A (such as hierarchical)? If so, Class B can extend class A and you will have access to class A's functions. If not, can you describe your two objects a little more (what they represent).

Comment: The thing is, Class A is already extending another class (simple_html_dom that I downloaded from the net) so I dont want to (dont even know if I can) extend Class A which is already extending some other class

Comment: @evert, I dont have any code... I was hoping someone could give me some code to do what I wrote above as I am stuck.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
//file1.php
<?php

class ClassA
{
   private $name = 'John';

   function getName()
   {
     return $this->name;
   }   
}
?>

//file2.php
<?php
   include ("file1.php");

   class ClassB
   {

     function __construct()
     {
     }

     function callA()
     {
       $classA = new ClassA();
       $name = $classA->getName();
       echo $name;    //Prints John
     }
   }

   $classb = new ClassB();
   $classb->callA();
?>
```

Comment: This is the one you want, even though it is currently negative.

Comment: Note that you cannot easily unit test your `B` class now, because you have tightly coupled to `A` class to it.

Comment: right - that include should probably be in a controlling file that calls both A and B instead of B including A. In this example you would always be instantiating A when you load B. But it should be easy for you to separate.

Comment: That's another lesson for the OP to learn another day... all the OP needs now is basics. Thanks for pointing that out anyway

Comment: Better learn the right way than starting on the wrong foot imo.

Comment: Just waiting on a peer review, but as of PHP 5.4, probably even in 5.3 the code would cause a fatal error: `classB()` is not a good class name. I've also reworded `prints` to `output` as this is the better definition of the language construct. `print_r` and its companions actually print information.

Comment: Where is `require_once` path? I have this scenario where I push an object data, and I separate the upload class. How do I call this two? If I `require_once[]..... /dbConnect.php`

Comment: Turns out I was missing an empty constructor

Answer (score 21):

If they are separate classes you can do something like the following:

```
class A
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'Some Name';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class B
{
    private $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    function getNameOfA()
    {
        return $this->a->getName();
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B($a);

$b->getNameOfA();
```

What I have done in this example is first create a new instance of the `A` class. And after that I have created a new instance of the `B` class to which I pass the instance of `A` into the constructor. Now `B` can access all the public members of the `A` class using `$this->a`.

Also note that I don't instantiate the `A` class inside the `B` class because that would mean I tighly couple the two classes. This makes it hard to:

1. unit test your `B` class
2. swap out the `A` class for another class

Comment: This one is good too but you specify two different files. So you just have to remember to include the class you want to instantiate with "new B()", etc

Comment: I read the question more as how can I access a member of another class than how can I include a file, but yeah you are right. Although autoloading files is something everybody should do for convenience imho.

Comment: Yeah definitely. Though at this stage I think autoloading might be overloading the learning process... perhaps.

Answer (score 11):

You would need to have an instance of ClassA within ClassB or have ClassB inherit ClassA

```
class ClassA {
    public function getName() {
      echo $this->name;
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    public function getName() {
      parent::getName();
    }
}
```

Without inheritance or an instance method, you'd need ClassA to have a static method

```
class ClassA {
  public static function getName() {
    echo "Rawkode";
  }
}
```

--- other file ---

`echo ClassA::getName();`

If you're just looking to call the method from an instance of the class:

```
class ClassA {
  public function getName() {
    echo "Rawkode";
  }
}
```

--- other file ---

```
$a = new ClassA();
echo $a->getName();
```

Regardless of the solution you choose, `require 'ClassA.php` is needed.

Comment: `ClassA::getName();` is the charm.

Answer (score 0):

File 1

```
class ClassA {

    public $name = 'A';

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

File 2

```
include("file1.php");
class ClassB {

    public $name = 'B';

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function callA(){
        $a = new ClassA();
        return $a->getName();
    }

    public static function callAStatic(){
        $a = new ClassA();
        return $a->getName();
    }

}

$b = new ClassB();
echo $b->callA();
echo $b->getName();
echo ClassB::callAStatic();
```

Comment: See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503734/php-calling-another-class-method/13503805#comment18482402_13503769) under @codingbiz's answer.